# How do I send an ajax request in a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send an ajax request in a chrome extension. My manifest:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Chrome Extension's message passing example",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/get_started32.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts":[{
    "matches":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js":["popup.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "background","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","webNavigation","tabs","notifications","https://example.com/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.foo === 'bar') {
    var url = "https://example.com/path";
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => sendResponse(response.text()))
        .catch(error => handleError(error))
      return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
  }
});

function handleError(error){
  console.log(error);
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({foo: 'bar'}, response => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

The popup data comes back as "{}" even though there is data from that url. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you try `alert(response)` instead?

Comment: I get `[object Object]`

Comment: So what is returned by that `fetch()`? And why does `response.text()` end up being an object? That's seems weird. It should be a string.

Comment: That url returns json: `{"key": "value"}`

Comment: response.text() returns a Promise, which can't be sent, duh. Use another then() like .then(r => r.text()).then(sendResponse)

Comment: Put that in an answer, duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `response.text()` [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), you need to add another `then` to resolve the Promise before sending it:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) =>
{
    if (msg.foo === 'bar')
    {
        var url = "https://example.com/path";
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text()
                .then(t => sendResponse(t))
            .catch(error => handleError(error))
        return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
});
```